# How to create Dropdown component depending on another components in React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to create a **Dropdown** component : `<Dropdown />`.

In this **Dropdown**, I would like a handler and a content to show. Always 2 elements inside this Dropdown.

This handler can be anything: Simple HTML, String or Component.

This content to show can be anything: Simple HTML, String or Component.

How can I a structure this `Dropdown` ? I would like to reuse it anywhere in my app.

I have this in mind.

```
<div id="Page2">
  <Dropdown>
    <Avatar />
    <Menu>
       <li>Settings</li>
       <li>Logout</li>
    </Menu>
  </Dropdown>
</div>
```

But it could be this :

```
<div id="Page3">
  <Dropdown>
    <span>Click to show the content</span>
    <div>Hello World</div>
  </Dropdown>
</div>
```

Component :

```
class Dropdown extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
       super(props);
   }
}
```

How can make `Avatar` or `<span>Click to show the content</span>` as handler?

I ask because it seems that Dropdown component have dynamic content but the operation is the same.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are looking for `props.children`. This is used to pass the children elements of a component to the component.

For example:

```
<DialogBox>
  <div>Title</div>
</DialogBox>
```

In the DialogBox component's render method:

```
return (
  <div class="dialog-box">
    {this.props.children}
  </div>
);
```

This will render:

```
<div class="dialog-box">
  <div>Title</div>
</div>
```

Read more about it here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html#containment